# Prove that each closed cycle in $G$ has a minimum length of $5$.

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

Given the following graph $G$:

[image]

How can I prove that each cycle in $G$ has a minimum length of $5$?

Comment: What about "by inspection"? How many cycles does your graph have? Are you allowed to use algebraic methods like the cycle space of a graph?

Comment: I 'm allowed to use also algebraic methods, besides those from graph theory. The thing is I cannot come with a formal proof.

Answer (score 1):

Draw the graph in a way that makes its symmetries more visible, like so:

[image]

Then solve the problem "by inspection", distinguishing cases: cycles passing through the red point or not, cycles containing $0$, $1$, or more blue points, etc.